# why the result is NaN?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 10;
sayHi();
function sayHi()
{
var a = a + 10;
alert(a);
return a;
}
alert(a);
alert(sayHi()+10);
```

why the above result is not 20 and 30? i feel the first is 20 , then 30.

Comment: Since you are declaring variable 'a' again in the function sayHI, Its becmoning UnDefined + 10 = UnDefined i.e NaN
If you remove 'var' in the function then you will get the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function sayHi()
{
   var a = a + 10;
   alert(a);
   return a;
}
```

is same as

```
function sayHi()
{
    var a;
    // a in this function will be the loacal variable a, which is undefined at first
    // a is undefined, undefined + 10 is NaN
    a = a + 10;
    alert(a);
    return a;
}
```

Check this article: [***JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting***](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)

If you want to use the global var `a`, you should not use `var a` inside the function.

But the better solution is to use the parameter.

```
function sayHi(a)
{
   a = a + 10;
   alert(a);
   return a;
}
```

Comment: what's the difference of var a; var a=1; do you mean if i declare var a; in a function, there is still undefined. except i give it some value? am i right?

Comment: `var a; var a=1;`  is same as `var a; a=1;`

Comment: but in sayHi() function, there is a line var a; i don't know why you said the a is  undefined

Comment: @stack01 Hi, did you check the article  i gave in the answer? Every var declaration will be put into top of the function.

Answer (score 1):

If `a` in the function is the same as the one declared on top, you shouldn't use `var` because it means redeclaring a new `a` variable. Also declare `sayHi` before using it. This would probably work as you expect:

```
var a = 10;

function sayHi()
{
a = a + 10; // No "var" keyword
alert(a);
return a;
}

sayHi();
alert(a);
alert(sayHi()+10);
```

Comment: in sayHi() function, there is a line var a; i don't know why the a is undefined。 thank you

Comment: @stack01, The line `var a` declares a **new** variable. Since it's new, it is initially undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 10;
sayHi();
function sayHi()
{
a = Number(a) + 10;
return (Number(a));
}
alert(a);
alert(sayHi()+10);
```

Comment: You may want to add some textual explanation of your change.

Comment: In the function sayHi() value was return in Number form not a string form and it sum of two numbers not concentrate the string

Answer (score 0):

Your function (as it is now) should always return `NaN`, no matter if your global `a = 10` or `a = 999` or if doesn't exist at all. This is because you are creating a totally different `a` inside your function with no value in it.

Two possible options:

**1) Use globals**

```
function updateValue(){
    a += 10;
    //don't need a return
}

var a = 10;
updateValue();
//'a' is now 20
```

**2) Return the value**

```
function getNewValue(num){
    num += 10;
    return num;
}

var a = 10;
a = getNewValue(a);
//'a' is now 20
```

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong, see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/uRCtw/) - any math operations with `undefined` will always result in NaN.